# Names of suppliers that offer only trucks and computers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been stuck on this one for a while. It is a lab and it's the last question. I combined the query I had above which one find the suppliers who only offer computers. Any help is appreciated.

```
 SELECT Name
 FROM Tb_Supplier
 WHERE Supp_ID IN
        (SELECT Supp_ID
        FROM Tb_Offers, Tb_Product
        WHERE Tb_Offers.Prod_ID = Tb_Product.Prod_ID
        AND (Tb_Product.Name = 'Computer'
          OR Tb_Product.Name = 'Truck'))
          AND Supp_ID NOT IN
            (SELECT Supp_ID
        FROM Tb_Offers, Tb_Product
        WHERE Tb_Offers.Prod_ID = Tb_Product.Prod_ID
        AND (Tb_Product.Name != 'Computer'
          OR Tb_Product.Name != 'Truck'))
```

I need to find only the Suppliers that supply Computer and Trucks and nothing else.

Comment: which column does supp_ID come from. I assume TB_offers

Comment: also the Or on the bottom boolean should be and AND

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Can it be Computers only, or Trucks only, or must be both Computers and Trucks?

Answer (score 0):

This gives a supplier that supplies Computers and Trucks, but nothing else

```
with dat
as
(
select 'Toronto' Supp_id,'Computer' thename union all
select 'Toronto' Supp_id,'Truck' thename union all
select 'Toronto' Supp_id,'Furniture' thename union all
select 'Ottawa' Supp_id,'Computer' thename union all
select 'Ottawa' Supp_id,'Truck' thename union all
select 'Montana' Supp_id,'Furniture' thename union all
select 'Idaho' Supp_id,'Computer' thename union all
select 'John' Supp_id,'Truck' thename union all
select 'John' Supp_id,'Furniture' thename union all
select 'Boris' Supp_id,'Computer' thename union all
select 'Boris' Supp_id,'Truck' thename union all
select 'Harold' Supp_id,'Furniture' thename union all
select 'Yelson' Supp_id,'Furniture' thename 
)
select Supp_ID from dat where thename = 'Computer'
intersect 
select Supp_ID from dat where thename = 'Truck'
except
select Supp_ID from dat where thename not in ('Truck','Computer')
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have provided, here's a solution.

```
SELECT tp.name,
       ts.supp_ID
FROM Tb_Supplier ts
inner join tb_offers tb on tb.supp_id = ts.supp_id
inner join tb_prodcut tp on tp.prod_id = tb.prod_id
WHERE ts.supp_ID not in (select ts.supp_ID
                         from Tb_Supplier ts
                         inner join tb_offers tb on tb.supp_id = ts.supp_id
                         inner join tb_prodcut tp on tp.prod_id = tb.prod_id
                         where tp.product not in ('computers', 'truck')
                        )
```

Comment: If supplier supply other items besides computer and truck, the query still picks up the supplier, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i've added a sub-query now which should get the required results. @Eric

Answer (score 0):

This requires **"Relational Division"**

Grouping and comparing the aggregations solves many problems requiring "ONLY" with a single pas through the data e.g.

```
select Supp_ID 
from yourdata
group by Supp_id
having sum(case when product_name not in ('Truck','Computer') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
and min(product_name) = 'Computer'
and max(product_name) = 'Truck'
;
```

If there is any other product the SUM() will be <> 0
and then min and max must then equal the 2 products

alternative:

```
select Supp_ID 
from yourdata
group by Supp_id
having sum(case when product_name not in ('Truck','Computer') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
and count(distinct product_name) = 2
;
```

This variant is easier to modify if there are more then 2 products to consider.

See: [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) (Joe Celko)